# Replacing the starting and ending months in ggplot in a time series in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I created a ggplot, where 3 different categorical variables are monthly evaluated, based on a dataframe (see example)

```
month  Asset_Class  n_assets
1           x          100
1           y          110
1           z          120
2           x          90
2           y          110
2           z          120
3           x          80
3           y          90
3           z          100
```

The code that i've written creates a faceted ggplot of the Asset_Class and the amount of times it occurs per month (n_assets):

```
df %>%
  mutate(month = as.Date(paste0("2020-", Month, "-01"),"%Y-%m-%d")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = month, y = n_assets)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label = n_assets), vjust = -0.5, color = "black", size = 3) +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b")  + facet_wrap(~ Asset_Class)
```

Currently, the ggplot first plots month 1, then month 2 etc. However, I am curious if there is a way to start the ggplot with month 3, following month 4, 5, 6 and finally end with month 2.

In short, I need to create a different starting month and ending month for the ggplot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this while preserving a `scale_date_x`, but if you are plotting a bar chart you don't need a continuous x scale anyway.

Therefore, the best way to do this is to convert the `month` column to a factor. That way, you can have it ordered however you like. You can specify a simple labelling function that converts the month numbers into month names as the `labels` parameter of `scale_x_discrete`:

```
df %>%
  mutate(month = factor(month, levels = c(3, 1, 2))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = month, y = n_assets)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label = n_assets), vjust = -0.5, color = "black", size = 3) +
  facet_wrap(~ Asset_Class) + 
  scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) month.abb[as.numeric(as.character(x))])
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this! I am also wondering whether it is possible to create a month.abb for every even or every odd month. Due to the number of levels I'm using (every month) it becomes quite unreadable

Comment: @WoutervanderValk if the months on your plot are unreadable, you could try changing the labelling function to plot an empty string every second month. Something like `labels = function(x) {y <- month.abb[as.numeric(as.character(x))]; y[seq_along(y) %% 2 == 0] <- ""; y}`